# XML to JSON or array? PHP

Tags: php, xml, json

I was thinking, it might be able to use and process XML data if i can run the XML through a func to validate it (against a schema) then convert the XML to json for easy object access? How can i convert XML to JSON easily?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml2jsonphp/

Comment: The best answer i have ever seen. No words, reference link, a great explanation and working code ;D

Answer (score 11):

```
$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlString));
$array = json_decode($json,true);
```

Comment: This is considerably more simple than the selected answer.