# read xml file and generate a json_encode format in php

Tags: php, xml, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML to JSON or array? PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521283/xml-to-json-or-array-php)

I have a xml file like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Leads/getCVRecords">
<result>
<Leads>
<row no="1">
<FL val="LEADID">580005000000189001</FL>
<FL val="SMOWNERID">580005000000052003</FL>
<FL val="Lead Owner"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="First Name"><![CDATA[Srimanta]]></FL>
<FL val="Last Name"><![CDATA[Chakraborty]]></FL>
<FL val="Email"><![CDATA[srimanta12@gmail.com]]></FL>
<FL val="Lead Source"><![CDATA[iBanquet FB]]></FL>
<FL val="No of Employees"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
<FL val="Annual Revenue"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
<FL val="SMCREATORID">580005000000052003</FL>
<FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="MODIFIEDBY">580005000000052003</FL>
<FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2013-01-22 12:24:04]]></FL>
<FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2013-01-22 12:24:04]]></FL>
<FL val="Email Opt Out"><![CDATA[false]]></FL>
<FL val="Last Activity Time"><![CDATA[2013-01-22 12:24:04]]></FL>
</row>
<row no="2">
<FL val="LEADID">580005000000188001</FL>
<FL val="SMOWNERID">580005000000052003</FL>
<FL val="Lead Owner"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="First Name"><![CDATA[Adithya]]></FL>
<FL val="Last Name"><![CDATA[Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="Email"><![CDATA[adithya.buddhavarapu@oracle.com]]></FL>
<FL val="Lead Source"><![CDATA[iBanquet FB]]></FL>
<FL val="No of Employees"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
<FL val="Annual Revenue"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
<FL val="SMCREATORID">580005000000052003</FL>
<FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="MODIFIEDBY">580005000000052003</FL>
<FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2013-01-21 19:14:44]]></FL>
<FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2013-01-21 19:14:44]]></FL>
<FL val="Email Opt Out"><![CDATA[false]]></FL>
<FL val="Last Activity Time"><![CDATA[2013-01-21 19:14:44]]></FL>
</row>
<row no="3">
<FL val="LEADID">580005000000166001</FL>
<FL val="SMOWNERID">580005000000052003</FL>
<FL val="Lead Owner"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="First Name"><![CDATA[Sri]]></FL>
<FL val="Last Name"><![CDATA[Nair]]></FL>
<FL val="Email"><![CDATA[sreejith_eroots@hotmail.com]]></FL>
<FL val="Lead Source"><![CDATA[iBanquet FB]]></FL>
<FL val="No of Employees"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
<FL val="Annual Revenue"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
<FL val="SMCREATORID">580005000000052003</FL>
<FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="MODIFIEDBY">580005000000052003</FL>
<FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
<FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2012-12-28 16:14:29]]></FL>
<FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2012-12-28 16:14:29]]></FL>
<FL val="Email Opt Out"><![CDATA[false]]></FL>
<FL val="Last Activity Time"><![CDATA[2012-12-28 16:14:29]]></FL>
</row>
</Leads>
</result>
</response>
```

Now I have to fetch all the values like LEADID, SMOWNERID, Lead Owner,....,Last Activity Time and store those in a json array. How can I do that? Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to parse the xml file with the appropriate function and encode it into an json object. So what about using the functions `xml_parse_into_struct`(there are a lot of others for xml decoding) and `json_encode`.

And maybe you should take a look at the general explanations on php and xml resp. json under http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php and http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php